# Printing Memory Address

Tags: c++

I ran the following program  on Cygwin on Windows8.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'b';
int i1 = 1;
float l1 = 100;
float f1 = 3.14;
double d1 = 1.424;
int i2;
char c3;
int i3;
printf("&c1 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&c1);
printf("&c2 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&c2);
printf("&i1 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&i1);
printf("&l1 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&l1);
printf("&f1 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&f1);
printf("&d1 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&d1);
printf("&i2 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&i2);
printf("&c3 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&c3);
printf("&i3 -> %u\n", (unsigned long)&i3);
}
```

My laptop gave the results below.

```
$ ./a.exe
&c1 -> 2337487
&c2 -> 2337486
&i1 -> 2337480
&l1 -> 2337476
&f1 -> 2337472
&d1 -> 2337464
&i2 -> 2337460
&c3 -> 2337459
&i3 -> 2337452
```

I understand that each data type has its own size and takes up memory addresses according to the size. For example, in this case, since `char` type has only 1 byte size, the variable `c1` takes up 1 memory address(2337487), and the next variable `c2` starts from the address 2337486. However, I was confused by that `i1` starts from 2337480. If `c2` is also a `char` type variable, shouldn't it take up only one address? And `i1` start from 2337485?

I guess it's something to do with a compiler, but don't understand how it works.Would anyone give me some advice?

Comment: The compiler prefers to place variable addresses at memory aligned addresses, that may take less operations to access or deal with a certain value.

Comment: Also, notice that these actually count from the bottom up.  So `c2` is only one address from the next variable `c1`.  So all the `int`s are at least four bytes away from the next variable up the list and the `char`s are one byte away.  I don't remember enough about how the compiler allocates memory to know why they are sequential in reverse.

Comment: They are stack allocated, that is why they count in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of data structure alignment.

For example, when the computer's word size is 4 bytes (a byte means 8 bits on most machines, but could be different on some systems), the data to be read should be at a memory offset which is some multiple of 4. When this is not the case, e.g. the data starts at the 14th byte instead of the 16th byte, then the computer has to read two 4 byte chunks and do some calculation before the requested data has been read, or it may generate an alignment fault. Even though the previous data structure ends at the 13th byte, the next data structure should start at the 16th byte. Two padding bytes are inserted between the two data structures to align the next data structure to the 16th byte.

Answer (score -1):

It's a compiler optimisation: somtimes it's faster when the allocated memory is not a solid block.